# What is the best starter adjustable power supply for pretty cheap (preferably ac/dc)

Tags: power-supply, power, ac-dc

Please I am just a kid no $8953739857239875 power supplies. Btw I am an inspiring electrical engineer and I'm 10 so I need a bit of help so I don't  how do I put this nicely, ahem trip the breaker if you know what I mean

Comment: Hi young man/woman. Welcome to EE.SE. I'd suggest you for your safety to have an adult technician while having fun with these stuff. Electricity is an amazing but dangerous thing. At your early stage you may need somebody to bring the voltage to 5 V DC, where you can have fun and innovate without risking your safety.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at our list of approved [topics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't actually like shopping recommendation questions here, and your question, as it looks right now, seems to be looking for a specific product as an answer.

Comment: For safety, you can use those volt "lantern batteries". No shock hazard. And a large diode (not 1N4148, but 1N4001 style) reduces the voltage to approximately 5.3 volts, good for logic experiments. Have you build a light-controlled LED driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I’m in the same boat as you (just 13 myself). By “adjustable power supply” do you mean adjustable voltage, current, or both?

If you want adjustable voltage, you can easily make one using something like an LM317, which is an adjustable voltage regulator.

If you want adjustable current, you can make your own using something as simple as a potentiometer, just check the power dissipation rating.

Building your own is probably the cheapest option, if possible. It’s also fun and a great learning experience (I’ve made an adjustable voltage supply). However, if you need adjustable voltage *and* current, that can get a bit trickier. If you know how to make one, go for it, but otherwise, [here’s a $40 one.](https://www.ebay.com/i/132250640502?chn=ps&var=431581318778&ul_ref=https%253A%252F%252Frover.ebay.com%252Frover%252F1%252F711-117182-37290-0%252F2%253Fmpre%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ebay.com%25252Fi%25252F132250640502%25253Fchn%25253Dps%252526var%25253D431581318778%2526itemid%253D431581318778_132250640502%2526targetid%253D548683525892%2526device%253Dt%2526adtype%253Dpla%2526googleloc%253D1014243%2526poi%253D%2526campaignid%253D1599024906%2526adgroupid%253D60762483792%2526rlsatarget%253Dpla-548683525892%2526abcId%253D1140366%2526merchantid%253D118848186%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQiA_s7fBRDrARIsAGEvF8SpM7e2tfGsgPR_6A-rRQoW-k5VT5PbcUCUmIyW20T_B72NR85dOJwaAoWhEALw_wcB%2526srcrot%253D711-117182-37290-0%2526rvr_id%253D1749776961713%2526rvr_ts%253D350432581670ad789146c45fffe40d6a) Not dirt-cheap, but it’s high quality, will last a while, and the holidays are coming up. Good luck!

Comment: I did not even expect a responce thank you for your time and I can't wait to get this and yes I will purchase it THANK YOU

Comment: @user205044 No problem. If the answer worked, you can mark it as accepted to show that it helped you and to let others know you don't need more responses.